# Get DirectX version by script UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, directx, raytracing

I want to know by script witch version of directX my project his.
(is for a Unity tool)

[Exemple here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pze2Y.png)

I want to use it like this :
`if(DirectX == "DX12") { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType.html), you can write something like this:

```
if (SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceType == GraphicsDeviceType.Direct3D12)
{
        
}
```